# DynamoDB updateItem creates new record

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

Its updating data if session is exists fine.

But when session is not exists its create a new row.At this stage , i dont want to do any action.

```
$sessionId = $params['session_id'];
    $response = $this->dbo->updateItem([
        'TableName' => $this->tableName,
        'Key' => [
            'id' => [ 'S' => $sessionId]
        ],
        'ExpressionAttributeValues' => [
            ':val1' => ['S' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]
        ],
        'UpdateExpression' => 'set sessionEnd = :val1',
        'attributeExists' => 'id',
        'ReturnValues' => "UPDATED_NEW"
    ]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `update item` API would create the new item if it doesn't exist. You can use `ConditionExpression` to stop creating the new item.

> Edits an existing item's attributes, or adds a new item to the table
>   if it does not already exist.

This means only if the id is already present, the update operation will happen. Also, it will stop creating the new item.

```
'ConditionExpression' => 'attribute_exists(id)',
```

If the key is not found, the API throws the below exception.

```
"code": "ConditionalCheckFailedException",
```